# Stopping repeated tasks forever

Tags: org-mode

Simple question: how to stop repeated tasks in Org (Emacs)?
A related subquestion would be how to set a repeated task for a period of time.
Let's say I want to do a certain task from January to March only, so I know when I am doing the last repetition.

Example:

```
    ** TODO TASK
    SCHEDULED: <2021-12-11 Sat .+1d>
    :PROPERTIES:
    :STYLE:    habit
    :LAST_REPEAT: [2021-12-10 Fri 14:30]
    :END:
    :LOGBOOK:
    - State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2021-12-10 Fri 14:30]
    - State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2021-12-09 Thu 00:16]
    - State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2021-12-07 Tue 18:20]
    [etc.]
    :END:
```

Is this possible at all?

Comment: Are you talking about `Org mode`? Or something else?

Comment: What @NickD said. The question is unclear. It might be deleted if not clarified. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

To mark a repeated task in Org as definitely done (cancelling the repeater), call `org-todo` with a -1 argument: `C-- 1 C-c C-t`, then mark it done.

And, no, it is not possible to set an end to a repeated task in Org. But you can easily make multiple copies of it with shifted schedules with `org-clone-subtree-with-time-shift`, bound by default to `C-c C-x c`.

Comment: Thanks, could you clarify what C-- 1 C-c C-t is? How do I type C--? When I click C- my text becomes smaller...

Comment: It is "hold Control, press hyphen/minus, then press 1". It is a numeric argument of "-1". You can do the same with `C-u - 1`, but this is a tad more convenient.

Comment: See https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Arguments.html. And if you type `C--` and "your text becomes smaller", it is probably because you've taken over the default binding for `text-scale-decrease`.

Comment: Thanks, guys. This is not working. When I do C-u-1 C-c C-t Emacs just tells me "TODO state was already TODO". This only changes the state to TODO, it does not mark the task as DONE and does not cancel the repeater.

Comment: What is the name of the function so I don't need to use my keyboard? Thanks.